# In The Time Machine, what was the point of there being so many hunter Morlocks?

Tags: the-time-machine-2002

Why would the Uber Morlocks need so many? Is it possible that, unlike the earlier version of the film, the Uber Morlocks were afraid of the Eloi and so needed an army? But that is sort of contradicted by the Uber's statement that the hunters would kill all the Eloi if not kept under control.

Comment: The Uber Morlocks were telepathic, so I guess they kept the hunters in check with some sort of telepathy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the scene where the hunters arrive in the village](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHPPeGoWDEU), the Eloi do offer *some* resistance to the Morlocks. Going mob-handed seems to actively discourage the Eloi from using any violence (they resort to running and hiding, mostly) and prevents the Morlocks from needing to use deadly force to protect themselves.

> The Eloi scramble desperately to protect their children -- the Morlocks are brutal -- great claws slamming Eloi aside or snatching them up -- nets swinging -- the Eloi never **really** resist -- once they are captured they allow the Morlocks to pull them away --
>
> <sub><sup>[Time Machine: 2002 Original Screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_2002)</sup></sub>

Having sufficient numbers also allows the Morlocks to perform an *encircling maneuver*, appearing in front of the Eloi as they're making for their boats and preventing them from escaping (which in turn allows them to capture their specific targets, apparently the fastest and smartest of the Eloi)

> Everywhere around them the Morlocks are netting Eloi and
>   dragging them away -- But it is not random.  The Morlocks seem to target particular Eloi.
>
> <sub><sup>[Time Machine: 2002 Original Screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_2002)</sup></sub>

---

As to why the Uber-Morlocks need quite so many Morlocks period, the answer is that they use them as physical labour to operate the machinery that keeps their subterranean world ticking along.

> Machines.  Towering, sweating, industrial.  A network of enormous pipes and electrical cables and air channels like the circulator system of a body that twist off in every direction.  A sweatshop Hell.  A mechanized Dante's Inferno
>   of wood and leather and steel.
>
> And the Morlocks are working.  All the machines are powered by the brute strength of the Morlocks alone.  They labor among the hellish machines -- slowly turning great wheels and pulling at enormous bellows and hauling ropes and grinding
>   levers.  They are nightmare figures of a Bosch painting.
>
> <sub><sup>[Time Machine: 2002 Original Screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_2002)</sup></sub>

Comment: Maybe a better question is, do we have any evidence that the Ubers have other projects than just eating and reproducing? Perhaps they do and need plenty of lower Morlocks for labor.

Comment: @releseabe - We also have some intel on that

Comment: Where do we get that intel and what sort of projects?

Comment: @releseabe  -See edit. The Morlocks were providing the physical labour to operate their machines.

Comment: yes, we saw that. but you would think they would develop engines. and i am wondering if the Ubers had long-term projects like space flight in mind or if Morlock culture was sort of stagnant.

Comment: They appear to have bastardised the existing machinery and then stopped there